# Term for set allowed to be either small or large

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Suppose you are assuming the axiom of universes, so that a "small" set relative to universe $U$ is one that is a member of $U$, and a "large" set is one that is not a member of $U$. Is there a commonly used term that includes both possibilities - applying to both small and large sets, but not proper classes (where a proper class is a collection that is not a member of any universe)?

Saying "let $x$ be a set" isn't ideal, since this is often taken to mean "let $x$ be a small set". One can say "let $x$ be a set (possibly large)", but this is quite clumsy. Any better options?

Comment: If you are assuming the universe axiom then there is almost never a need to talk about genuine proper classes, so you could redefine "class" to mean possibly-large-set. Or you could introduce a new word – "collection", "ensemble", "conglomerate"...

Comment: Say "$x$ is a set". If the reader reads that as saying anything more than that $x$ is a set that's the reader's problem